# Autowired @Resource in new thread never touched, unless in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, spring-boot

I am writing a spring-boot app that has a REST controller my front-end talks to. When I call the controller it inserts a name into the queue. The processor below checks the `incomingQueue` and performs an action on the database each using the latest name in the queue.

Here is where I am totally stumped. My code works when I am in debug mode in eclipse, but when I simply run the application the queue never gets touched by the code below. No output from the line `System.out.println(name + " removed from queue. Queue size now: " + incomingQueue.size());` is ever called.

Any advice why this is?

**REST Controller:**

```
@Resource
Queue<String> incomingQueue;

@RequestMapping(value="/simpleAction",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody int queueName(@RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name) throws RiotApiException {
    incomingQueue.add(name);
    return incomingQueue.size();
}
```

**Request Processor:**

```
@Component
public class RequestProcessor implements Runnable {

@Resource
Queue<String> incomingQueue;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

public SimpleAction getSimpleAction() {
    return (SimpleAction) context.getBean("simpleAction");
}


public void run(){
    System.out.println("Spawning Request Processor");

    while (true) {
        if (!incomingQueue.isEmpty()) {
            String name = incomingQueue.remove();
            System.out.println(name + " removed from queue. Queue size now: " + incomingQueue.size());
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     getSimpleAction().performAction(name);
                 }
            }).start();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

How I start the Request Processor:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    RequestProcessor requestProcessor;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        new Thread(requestProcessor).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that   getSimpleAction().performAction(name); is also not called or its just the sysout ,may be your logger setting are set such that only in debug sysout prints. can you check.

Comment: My god @gladiator looks like it was running, but I switched to log4j framework and everything is printing now. Such a dumb mistake, but thanks for the solution.